# Python Social Auth : Changing the UID in the pipeline

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using Django and the latest python-social-auth. I have the pipeline currently as below. It was working 100% until I introduced into the 'registration.extra_registration_details' function a piece of code that accepts a generated uid from another internal service and sets the Django uid of the userprofile to be that. This breaks the pipeline because (I think) the social auth user in the pipeline is already attached to the previous uid but moving that function up or down doesn't fix anything.

(Note that the curious way that registration process works is because I'm adding this on to an old project and it works in some idiosynratic way)

Pipeline:

```
#python-social oauth pipeline that can be augmented and added to
PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'registration.email_as_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'registration.extra_registration_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

Code that changes uid (in extra_registration_details):

```
    uid = fetchUserUID(user.id)
    user.get_profile().uid = uid
```

the rest of the changes to the profile work perfectly if I comment the above two lines out.

So what part of the pipeline should I be working with to manually change the uid of the user being created, without breaking the normal pipeline funcitons? Thanks

Comment: I want to add a suggestion (and then take a break if someone wants to chip in). What if I make a completely custom create_user step and put it BEFORE associate_by_email. Therefore the App will check to see and see that user already exists and attaches to that? Does that sound sensible and does anyone more familiar with the pipeline have any warnings.